# Is there a python code or excel function for doing non linear interpolation?

Tags: python, excel, interpolation, curve-fitting, prediction

[Image of the problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ad8.jpg)

X are the number of months
Y are the sequence of cash

If x is decreased or increased to any random length of months what should be the sequence of Y? Also sum of Y should remain 1028?

Tried finding the trend and used slope fuctions.